# How a variable will store tab delimited columns in linux

Tags: linux, csv, variables

I have a file e.g.,

```
chr1 42922025 42922975 5.706205956057661
chr1 42800249 42801531 5.706205956057661
chr1 42725241 42725739 5.706205956057661
chr1 42724653 42725061 5.706205956057661
chr1 42723583 42724111 5.706205956057661
```

I want to store this file to use as input in the pipe next. I used the command to define variable is `myfile=$(cat myfile)`

However, this command returns the tab delimited columns as a single line. My expected command to use the TSV file as a variable in a pipe is:
 `myfile=$(cat myfile) | paste $myfile myfile2`

Thanks in advance!

Comment: we need to see sample data for file2 and your expected output. In the meantime `paste` will try to interpret any string on the cmdline (i.e. the value of `"$myfile"`) as a list of files. Not clear why you need `"$myfile"` when you can just "say" `paste myfile myfile2`. Also read `man paste` to see how to deal with delimiters. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks! myfile2 is similar TSV format as myfile. I used paste command as an example. I will fed the myfile variable into a software and therefore did not mention the command for the software. So, I want to store the TSV file into a variable.

Comment: OK, well be sure you use dbl-quotes on all variables, i.e. `echo "$myfileVar" | cat -vet` for example. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks! echo is not helpful in my case. I can not use `paste (echo "$myfileVar" | cat -vet) myfile2`, getting error `-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `echo`.

Comment: You had said  you were using `paste` as a stand-in for a "real" program, I tried to make it even simpler, and used `cat -vet` as the stand-in program. Don't expect `paste` to recognize `(echo .. | cat -vet)` as a valid argument. Still not clear what you are really trying to do. Did you try `echo "$myfileVar" | yourProblematicProgram` (without surrounding `( ... )`s? Good luck.